# kubernetes external secrets on GKE , Permission error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, secretsmanager

I install [kubernetes external secrets](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets) with helm, on GKE.

- GKE: 1.16.15-gke.6000 on asia-northeast1
- helm app version 6.2.0
- using Workload Identity [as document written](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets#deploy-kubernetes-external-secrets-using-workload-identity)

For workload identity,the service account I bind as below command (my-secrets-sa@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has **SecretManager.admin** role, which seems necessary for using google secrets manager

> gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser --member "serviceAccount:$CLUSTER_PROJECT.svc.id.goog[$SECRETS_NAMESPACE/kubernetes-external-secrets]" my-secrets-sa@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Workload identity looks set correctly, because checking service account in pod on GKE shows correct serviceaccount

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#enable_workload_identity_on_a_new_cluster

create a pod in cluster and check auth in it. it shows `my-secrets-sa@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

> $ kubectl run -it  --image google/cloud-sdk:slim --serviceaccount ksa-name --namespace k8s-namespace workload-identity-test
>
> $ gcloud auth list

But even if creating externalsecret, externalsecret shows error

> ERROR, 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/project-id/secrets/my-gsm-secret-name/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).

secret `my-gsm-secret-name` itself exist in secretmanager, so it should not "not exist".
Also permission must be correctly set by workload identity.

it's the externalsecret I defined.

```
apiVersion: kubernetes-client.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: gcp-secrets-manager-example    # name of the k8s external secret and the k8s secret
spec:
  backendType: gcpSecretsManager
  projectId: my-gsm-secret-project
  data:
    - key: my-gsm-secret-name     # name of the GCP secret
      name: my-kubernetes-secret-name   # key name in the k8s secret
      version: latest    # version of the GCP secret
      property: value      # name of the field in the GCP secret
```

Has anyone had similar problem before ?
Thank you

### whole command

1. create a cluster with workload-pool.

> $ gcloud container clusters create cluster --region asia-northeast1 --node-locations asia-northeast1-a --num-nodes 1 --preemptible --workload-pool=my-project.svc.id.goog

2. create kubernetes service account.

> $ kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace default ksa

3. binding kubernetes service account & service account

> $ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding 
> --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser 
> --member "serviceAccount:my-project.svc.id.goog[default/ksa]" 
> my-secrets-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

4. add annotation

> $ kubectl annotate serviceaccount 
> --namespace default 
> ksa 
> iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=my-secrets-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

5. install with helm

> $ helm install my-release external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets

6. create external secret

```
apiVersion: kubernetes-client.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: gcp-secrets-manager-example    # name of the k8s external secret and the k8s secret
spec:
  backendType: gcpSecretsManager
  projectId: my-gsm-secret-project
  data:
    - key: my-gsm-secret-name     # name of the GCP secret
      name: my-kubernetes-secret-name   # key name in the k8s secret
      version: latest    # version of the GCP secret
      property: value      # name of the field in the GCP secret
```

> $ kubectl apply -f excternal-secret.yaml

Comment: Does `my-secrets-sa@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com` have role *Secret Manager Secret Accessor* on your project ?

Comment: norbjd may be right. 
Can you add `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` Role in `IAM & Admin` to your `Service Account` ?

Comment: Yes, I added Secret Manager Secret Accessor role to `my-secrets-sa@$PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com` but still same error.

Comment: I updated issue; adding all commands I executed for install

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that I had used different kubernetes service account.

When installing helm, new kubernetes service account `my-release-kubernetes-external-secrets` was created, and service/pods must be working on this service account.

So I should bind `my-release-kubernetes-external-secrets` & google service account.

Now, it works well.

Thank you @matt_j @norbjd